# Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug' Adding jersey dependencies give build error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I created an Android project in Intellij with empty activity. And then I added Jersey libraries as dependencies in gradle as follow :

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

  // dependencies I added
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19'
```

}

It started showing following error :

Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Hey @Kuldeep kindly reply if my answer solved ur problem or not ?

Comment: run ./gradlew assemble --info and post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Kuldeep usually this error is because of multiple file with the same name you must check where is the redundant file and remove it maybe this is from the newly added library also try to add this inside of android tag in gradle file of your project

```
   packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

}
```

Comment: The project is freshly created so no chance of duplicate files and when I add packagingOptions to gradle then it gives : 

Error:(39, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()'
Possible causes: 
The project 'Android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.